# In C++, why are cyclical directory dependencies bad?

Tags: c++, directory-structure

I'm asking this about a C++ project developed on Linux.  Consider this:

I have two peer directories, `dir1` and `dir2`.  `dir1` contains `classA.h` and `classB.h`.  `dir2` contains `classC.h` and `classD.h`.  `dir1/classA.h` has an `#include` for `dir2/classC.h`. `dir2/classD.h` has an `#include` for `dir1/classB.h`.  As a result, there is a cyclical dependency between directories `dir1` and `dir2`. However, there are no cyclical dependencies between any classes.

I understand why cyclic dependencies are bad between classes.  It seems intuitive to me that directories should also not have cyclical dependencies--however I can't figure out why this would be bad.

Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Are there any indirect cycles, like `classC.h` including `classD.h` or something?

Comment: There are no indirect cycles among the .h files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not bad. At least not the way you stated the problem. Directories are meant to organize files, but programatically have no meaning.

**However** if your directories represent separate modules (i.e. there is a generated library file for each directory), you will have linking errors.

Because `classA` depends on `classC`, you need to build the second module in order to compile the first one. But the second module needs the first module to be built first, since `classD` depends on `classB`.

Answer (score 0):

Like for classes cyclic dependencies for directories can be an issue for **maintainability** and **reuse**.

**Maintainability**: when a "module" (in this case a directory) has dependencies on another module, whenever the other modules changes, the change can affect this module.
**Reuse**: when reusing a module, you must also reuse the modules it depends on.

So with cyclic dependencies, all modules are affected.  This isn't a real problem with a limited amount of modules, but it grows together with the growing amount.

Comment: This makes sense to me when discussing files and libraries--but I'm not getting it for directories.  Could you expand a bit or provide an example where this causes a problem when the cycle is only at the directory level?  Thanks.

Comment: Putting files in a directory is a way of organizing, so it should make sense to reuse the complete directory as a sort of module.  Cyclic dependency minimizes the chance for reuse.  For maintainability, if dependencies are not cyclic, we can predict what directories can be impacted, with (many) cyclic dependencies, every change can impact the whole system.